# ios 5 screen auto orientation

Tags: ios, xcode, screen-orientation

Xcode 4.6 and there is an app where did support IOS 5.0
When running the application on the IOS simulator 6 - auto rotate works when IOS 5 - no.
Same thing on the devices.

Used StoryBoard.

Boolean values ​​during injection capabilities autorotation - true.

Comment: place your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS6 introduced new methods for deciding if a view should rotate, but for iOS5 you would still need to use the old methods - it could be you are using the iOS6 methods only.  Here is what I use:

```
// New iOS6 autorotate interface.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

// Older autorotate interface (for compatibility).
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    else
        return YES;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work.
i wrote into the end of AppDelegate.m

Comment: It should be in the view controller class, not AppDelegate.m.

Comment: i added this block after @implementation ViewController, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: heh, A UITabBarController will only autorotate if all of its view controllers are set to autorotate.

Answer (score 0):

for ios5 use

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
     return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

but the above method is deprecated for ios6 as to override that use this

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: write that in the view controller that is being presented

Comment: i added this block after @implementation ViewController, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: heh, A UITabBarController will only autorotate if all of its view controllers are set to autorotate.